# Can we assign Azure Blueprint to a resource or a resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azureportal, azure-policy, azure-blueprints

We may assign Roles, Policies, ARM templates and Resource groups to users via Azure Blueprints during deployments at organization's scope or to one or more subscriptions. But can we do the vice-versa. I mean can a VNET or VM be assigned to interact with some other user via Azure Blueprints.
This is a deployment question raised by my management. We currently are searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Published Version of an Azure Blueprint can be assigned only to an existing management group or subscription.

For more information read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/overview#blueprint-assignment).

Comment: I think the doc is bit mis-leading. Because at the end it only makes sense to assign resources to Subscription(s). And infact Subscription is the only option that you can see to assign a BP to.